# How to delete directory content with launchd

Tags: macos, script, launchd

I am trying to empty a directory at the end of the day, so I have written the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.script.removetemp</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>rm</string>
        <string>-fr</string>
        <string>/tmp/test/*</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>45</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>23</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I named it `com.my.script.removetemp.plist` and placed it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, but it doesn’t work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell globbing (`<string>/tmp/test/*</string>`) is not supported by launchd!

You can **either** remove the whole folder *test* `<string>/tmp/test</string>` **or** launch a shell script *rmtestcontent* (in the example */usr/local/bin/rmtestcontent*) with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/rm -fr /tmp/test/*
```

with the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.script.removetemp</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/rmtestcontent</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>45</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>23</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

to empty the directory */tmp/test*.

Comment: +1 For the diagnosis and the solution I like (since delete requirements get heavier over time, might as well script it)

Comment: I wonder how many questions about `launchd` scripts would be eliminated if everyone used [`Launch Control`](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/)?